# Cleaning up a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

i'm new to react and i was wondering if there was a way that i could clean up this function to make it more simple? What i'm trying to do is update a user by finding it in my database for the user in that city.

```
const registerUser = async (user: string, city: Cities[]): Promise<Cities | null> => {

      const updatedUser = await db.User.findOneAndUpdate({ name: user }, { $addToSet: { city: cities } }, { new: true });

      // this line 
      return updatedUser?.city.find((c: Cities) => c.id == city.id) ?? null;
};
```

Comment: Maybe a comment? If it works, it works. That doesn't seem too convoluted or confusing.

Comment: I think there are maybe mistakes in your code. The `city` argument to `registerUser` seems like it should be `cities` since its type is an array (and you reference a `cities` variable which doesn't exist in the db lookup). And then the callback in `find` is trying to compare an `id` property from that `city` array which will be undefined to a `c.id`. Is the `Cities[]` type for `city` in the arguments correct? It's also confusing for the type `Cities` to refer to a singular city in my opinion.